# Include link anchor text in xpath text extraction?

Tags: html, xpath

I have a series of `<p>` tags, an example:

```
<p>normal text<a href="#">link anchor text</a>more normal text</p>
```

the XPath `//p/text()` doesn't include "link anchor text", how can I include it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`//p/text()` asks for all text nodes that are *direct children* of `p` elements. You could ask for `//p//text()`, but I'm guessing you are actually looking for `string(//p)`.

Comment: string(//p) is exactly it, thank you very much! Will accept the answer when it lets me in a few minutes.